# How to change Run IDs for DAG executions triggered via REST API of Airflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

We are triggering DAGs in Google Cloud Composer via Airflow's REST interface.
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/deprecated-rest-api-ref.html

We can see that the DAGs triggered this way get Run IDs with `manual__` prefix, e.g.:

```
Run Id
manual__2021-06-25T05.52.31.103391+00.00
```

When we trigger these DAGs from Cloud Functions want to differentiate these executions from the manually executed DAGs (triggered from UI) or from automatically scheduled executions (triggered by cron/scheduling criteria).

**Question:** Is it possible to mark the executions triggered via REST API other than `manual__`?

Sidenote: currently we are using Composer with Airflow 1.x, but we are planning to change to Airflow 2.x as soon as the Composer supports it.

Answer (score 4):

It can not be changed.

Airflow has Enum of [DagRunType](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/utils/types.py#L26:L28) with 3 options: `backfill`, `scheduled` & `manual`. The value is set by Airflow itself.